# phpbb - new topic not created and get reditect to topic creation page

Tags: php, phpbb

I have a phpbb forum hosted in a testing machine and is working 100%.

I deployed it to production and everything look ok, except the submission of new topics and posts.
It's strange because when I submit the post I'm redirected to new topic (or post) page without any feedback... And in the testing machine it works!

I checked out permissions and they look ok. Cache files look ok as well.

Thanks.

Edit:
I tested some echos on posting.php and there are no values on $_POST... However in the local machine $_POST have the right values...

Comment: Have you the server configuration, server settings URLs correctly? They're found under the General tab.

Comment: Yes, URLs are ok... Thanks